# Why m-n higher bits give page number and n lower bits give offset?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging

I was reading **Operating System Concepts by Galvin**.Under the topic **Paging**, I came to know that, if the size of the logical address space is **2^m**, and a page size is **2^n** addressing units (bytes or words), then the high-order **m-n** bits of a logical address designate the page number, and the **n** low-order bits designate the page offset.

I could not figure out why is it so, so please provide an explanation for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for using the high bits is locality. When you access elements from data structures like array, stack or record (aka. struct in C), these elements are located nearby each other. So the addresses probably only differ in the least significant bits, leaving the most significant bits unchanged. This means that the elements are mostly in the same page.

Suppose you would use the low bits for page number. To make things easier remove two or three least significant bits so the address is machine word aligned. Elements that were next to each other are now always in different pages. Also elements that are bigger than a word are now split in multiple pages.

The same reason also applies to caches.